# How do I create multiple groups of weight paint?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

How do I create multiple groups of weight paint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding an additional vertex group under Properties > Data > Vertex Groups.

[image: Add additional Vertex Group for Weight Painting]

Edit: Here's the location in Blender 2.8+

[image: Add additional Vertex Group for Weight Painting in Blender 2.8+]